# In an application or for the system, how do I bind more than one key to a shortcut?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I have two keyboards. One is built-in to my laptop, the other is an external keyboard I use when docked. They have slightly different key mappings for things like multimedia keys.

For that reason, I'd like to make multiple assignments to a handful of keyboard shortcuts. My external keyboard doesn't have a Windows button, so I'd like to launch Unity Dash (for example) using *either* a Windows/logo button, or to a specific keybinding.

Is there any way to make multiple assignments this way in Gnome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) to bind a shortcut to another shortcut:

1) Install [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool).

2) Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and paste `gnome-control-center keyboard`.

3) Go to the "Shortcuts" tab and then to "Custom shortcuts".

4) Press at "+" to add a new shortcut:

[image]

5) Give it a name and at the command you paste something like this:

`gnome-terminal --geometry=0x0 -e "bash -c \"sleep .1 && xdotool keydown --clearmodifiers Super && xdotool keyup Super ; exit; exec bash\""`

6) Press at "Disabled" and then press the key combination you want.

[image]

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Any reason for the gnome-terminal part, instead of using xdotool directly?

Comment: The reason is that oddly the gnome shortcuts doesn't execute commands, so we have to first open a terminal.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106754/why-we-cant-run-commands-with-gnome-shortcuts

Comment: Weird how Gnome 2.x had an option to execute a command in a terminal or not. I guess that functionality was removed.