# Why we can't run commands with gnome shortcuts?

Tags: gnome, bash, gnome-terminal, shortcuts, shortcut-keys

When I make a custom shortcut with gnome (`gnome-control-center keyboard`) I can't set it to a command. Why?

Example: I can't set a shortcut for `sudo apt-get update`. Instead I must first invoke a graphical terminal, then bash, then execute the command (something like: `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"sudo apt-get update ; exec bash\""`

Also is there another (better) workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. You've just shown you can! You can even simplify it a little:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "sudo apt-get update"
```

It needs a terminal because it's interactive (because of `sudo`). If you just want to suppress the password request, you could edit your `/etc/sudoers` file so it doesn't require a password for `apt-get`. In my opinion, this isn't great because it might be abused.

For this command there is another option: Aptdaemon. This is what the Software Centre and Update Manager now use for permissions (it uses PolicyKit and it's designed on PackageKit). To update apt, just run:

```
aptdcon -c
```

That shouldn't require a password and if it does, it should be able to pop up a PolicyKit box without needing a terminal to be spawned.

Comment: It feels like you didn't really answer his question, which I interpreted to mean, "Why do we have to wrap up commands with 'gnome-terminal ...'". Maybe it's just my interpretation, and he was really just interested in the sudo details.

What actually interprets/runs the custom keyboard shortcuts anyway?