# How can i make my custom key shortcut

Tags: shortcuts

I would like to know how i can make my custom key shortcut to run an executable file located on my desktop, and i would like to use the key command of CTRL+F to activate it.
THANKS!

Comment: This question is horribly specific.  There are more general questions on defining keyboard shortcuts already on site.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier helping me out rather than criticizing  my question?

Comment: It would be easier for you to actually search the site before asking duplicate questions.

Comment: I did search the site and i found nothing of what i wanted

Comment: There, you got your answer

Comment: I love you, dude.<3

Answer (score 2):

First:
This question is a duplicate of a general creating shortcuts question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106754/why-we-cant-run-commands-with-gnome-shortcuts).

Second:
You shouldn't store executables on your desktop, put it in ~/bin or something.

Third:

```
mkdir ~/bin
mv ~/Desktop/my_random_executable ~/bin
```

Fourth:
Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106754/why-we-cant-run-commands-with-gnome-shortcuts) question and use the answer.

Fifth:
That question was the third search result for [this query](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=gnome-control-center+shortcut).

Thanks.  Have a nice day.